# Keras/TensorFlow I'm Having Trouble Using GPUs, CPUs, and Other Hardware Efficiently

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have access to a 2018 Lambda machine with 24 CPUs and 4 GPUs and a 4 TB SSD. I also have access to a 2022 Dell with 40 CPUs and 3 A6000 GPUs and a 1TB NVMe SSD in addition to a 1TB SSD and 2 8TB HDDs.

If I restrict my Python/Keras/TensorFlow code to use 1 CPU and 1 GPU, it takes about 9-10 minutes per epoch to run with about 40k parameters. If I increase the number of CPUs available or the number of GPUs available or both, it still takes 9-10 minutes per epoch. In the beginning, the disks are heavily taxed as the data is read into memory, but apparently, it all fits into memory because, after a while, it appears that there is no disk activity.

I used atop to monitor resource usage and that is how I found out about the disk activity.

I used htop to monitor CPU activity and I found that if only one CPU is used, it is heavily taxed. If 2 CPUs are used, they are each taxed at about 60% capacity. For 10 CPUs, each is used at about 13% capacity, and with 20 CPUs, each is used at about 7% capacity.

I used nvtop to monitor GPU activity and it appears, on the Dell, that one GPU is utilized at about 10-25% capacity while the other two are rarely used. In fact, it appears that no data is read into the memory of GPU1 or GPU2. Only GPU0 appears to be doing something real. Previously using nvidia-smi revealed similar behavior on the Lambda machine.

I am using the Keras model.fit with my own data generator function. I would think that using multiple CPUs would cause the data generator to be run in parallel on several CPUs to keep the queue full, but the CPUs seem mostly idle.

So, the CPUs appear to be underutilized, the GPUs appear to be underutilized, and the disks appear to be underutilized. Either there is some other source of bottlenecking or the main memory/PCI-bus can't keep up. Or maybe Keras just isn't running more than one copy of the data generator. At this point, I'm at a complete loss.

BTW, I'm using Python 3.8 and TensorFlow 2.10.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Some more information:
I can't say exactly what the application is, but the network currently has two Siamese branches each having 17 convolutional layers performing 3x3 convolutions in a telescoping arrangement. The input images are 69x69 and the smallest layer is 5x5. The input layer has 3 channels and subsequent layers each have 16 channels. Following that are three dense layers with 25, 20, and 10 units. Following that, the two Siamese branches are combined in a product layer with 10 outputs and those outputs are combined by another dense layer with 1 output. There is also a custom loss function which is similar to the binary cross-entropy loss. The input dataset consists of about 600,000 images.

On the advice of a colleague, I turned off all the GPUs and am running purely on CPUs. Under that condition, it appears that all 40 CPUs on the Dell are being utilized at between 20% and 50% of capacity with one CPU sometimes using  95+% of capacity. It appears that under this condition, the time increases to about 12-13 minutes per epoch.

I should also mention that I'm using a batch size of 500. I've tried increasing or decreasing the batch size, but the run time does not appear to be greatly affected. If anything, it just gets slower.

Thanks.

Comment: There is always a bottleneck, and you did not mention what exactly you are training, maybe the model you have is too simple.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I added some more information above.